# Using tensorflow TFRecords for a dataset with multi task

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I want Use `TFRecords`  for [celeba face dataset](http://mmlab.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/projects/CelebA.html). celeba face datase has 5 landmark locations, 40 binary attributes annotations per image.

`TFRecords`  only can give one lable. but I want save all this labels in TFRecords.
How can do this in tensorflow?

---

My solution is :
I use [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/convert_to_records.py#L66) to create `TFRecords` file.
Then I convert celeba attribute file to `.csv` and read it by `_dataset = pd.read_csv("./List_attr_celeba.csv")`.

Then add path to it with `_dataset["path"] = './img_align_celeba/' + _dataset["name"]`. (I used align images the was in `img_align_celeba` folder).

for first then features I used `labels = _dataset.ix[:,1:11].as_matrix()`.

In the code of :

`example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'height': _int64_feature(rows),
        'width': _int64_feature(cols),
        'depth': _int64_feature(depth),
        'label': _int64_feature(int(labels[index])),
'image_raw': _bytes_feature(image_raw)}))`

label must be `'(<class 'int'>,)`, but `labels[index]`  has type `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`.

So I changed:

`example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
                'height': _int64_feature(rows),
                'width': _int64_feature(cols),
                'depth': _int64_feature(depth),
                'label': _int64_feature(labels[index].tolist()),
                'image_raw': _bytes_feature(image_bytes)}))
            writer.write(example.SerializeToString())`

and :

`def _int64_feature(value):
  if  type(value)!= list:
      value = [value]
  return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=value))`

Answer (score 0):

I think each record you write is proto buffer to be defined by you, and you can include whatever you need in the proto buffer.

Here is an example proto buffer, which I believe you can reuse to include as many labels as you want with each label as a separate Feature:  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/convert_to_records.py#L66
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/example/example.proto#L88
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/example/feature.proto

Comment: My problem was that I used `numpy` `array`. But I used `tolist()` function for `labels[index]` and it convert numpy.int32 to int.

Comment: This sounds fine. Could you elaborate/clarify what the problem is?

Comment: I add it in question.